# The notification area doesn't show up when I slide down on the notification bar. What could be the issue?

Tags: notifications, android-12, google-pixel-6

The notification area doesn't show up when I slide down on the notification bar. What could be the issue?

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround: locking and unlocking the screen seems to solve the issue Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. However this  doesn't prevent the issue from appearing from time to time.